# Calculating Pooled Estimate of Variance in R

Tags: r, dataframe, variance

I have a dataset like below and I want to estimate the 'Pooled estimate of variance' for this dataset.

This dataset is having two groups of columns (first three columns "A1", "A2", "A3" are one group and next three columns "B1", "B2", "B3" are second group)

```
structure(list(A1 = c(12305960196.5721, 24169710612.0476, 32972077491.8103, 
8553811608.70032, 13176265141.6301, 92994780469.5607), A2 = c(11629654800, 
25162283400, 31864546300, 8157173240, 12812379370, 90007498700
), A3 = c(12503938417.8663, 25733015601.0117, 34727094361.2997, 
8857104380.18179, 12763602767.3278, 93988723611.341), B1 = c(14380818076.1189, 
79582218995.1549, 77615759060.3497, 21749287984.8341, 33342436650.5148, 
101254055758.836), B2 = c(21440113143.2507, 78743355495.2545, 
81948536416.9992, 23764549283.2733, 34617564902.3219, 99485017820.8478
), B3 = c(20385779423.3852, 80272416055.8845, 77019098847.8474, 
23045479130.9574, 32885483296.8046, 90789109337.1181)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`57` = 57L, 
`124` = 124L, `125` = 125L, `152` = 152L, `164` = 164L, `167` = 167L, 
`168` = 168L, `169` = 169L, `172` = 172L, `174` = 174L, `176` = 176L, 
`178` = 178L, `179` = 179L, `180` = 180L, `181` = 181L, `185` = 185L, 
`188` = 188L, `190` = 190L, `191` = 191L, `196` = 196L, `197` = 197L, 
`199` = 199L, `200` = 200L, `201` = 201L, `202` = 202L, `205` = 205L, 
`207` = 207L, `208` = 208L, `210` = 210L, `214` = 214L, `215` = 215L, 
`216` = 216L, `217` = 217L, `221` = 221L, `224` = 224L, `226` = 226L, 
`227` = 227L, `228` = 228L, `229` = 229L, `231` = 231L, `232` = 232L, 
`236` = 236L, `237` = 237L, `239` = 239L, `242` = 242L, `245` = 245L, 
`249` = 249L, `253` = 253L, `257` = 257L, `258` = 258L, `273` = 273L, 
`274` = 274L, `281` = 281L, `290` = 290L, `317` = 317L, `322` = 322L, 
`325` = 325L, `330` = 330L, `336` = 336L, `345` = 345L, `349` = 349L, 
`353` = 353L, `354` = 354L, `356` = 356L, `392` = 392L, `403` = 403L, 
`404` = 404L, `409` = 409L, `426` = 426L, `434` = 434L, `543` = 543L, 
`545` = 545L, `563` = 563L, `574` = 574L, `600` = 600L, `623` = 623L, 
`624` = 624L, `632` = 632L, `633` = 633L, `638` = 638L, `642` = 642L, 
`663` = 663L, `709` = 709L, `727` = 727L, `746` = 746L, `796` = 796L, 
`849` = 849L, `1730` = 1730L), class = "omit"))
```

Please suggest some R code for calculating pooled estimate of variance.[image: Formula for Pooled estimate of variance]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Now I modified my question. Please see once.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use the `utilities` package with the `sample.decomp` function like this:

```r
library(utilities)
library(moments)
N <- sapply(df, length)
MEAN <- sapply(df, mean)
VAR <- sapply(df, var)
SKEW <- sapply(df, skewness)
KURT <- sapply(df, kurtosis)

sample.decomp(n = N, 
              sample.mean = MEAN,
              sample.var  = VAR,
              sample.skew = SKEW,
              sample.kurt = KURT,
              names       = names(df))
#>             n sample.mean   sample.var sample.skew sample.kurt
#> A           6 30695434253 1.012864e+21  1.48900482    3.629503
#> B           6 29938922635 9.475501e+20  1.46579309    3.593486
#> C           6 31428913190 1.034617e+21  1.44777337    3.548699
#> D           6 54654096088 1.295811e+21  0.08531486    1.341991
#> E           6 56666522844 1.153917e+21  0.08593435    1.253710
#> F           6 54066227682 1.021490e+21  0.01378374    1.145876
#> --pooled-- 36 42908352782 1.078188e+21  0.62178383    1.692347
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

`sample.decomp` according to documentation:

> sample.decomp returns the data-frame of sample statistics for sample
> groups and their pooled sample

If you want to calculate the Pooled estimate of variance for A and B for example, you can use the following code:

```
n1 <- length(df$A)
n2 <- length(df$B)
var1 <- var(df$A)
var2 <- var(df$B)

pooled <- ((n1-1)*var1 + (n2-1)*var2) / (n1+n2-2)
> pooled
[1] 9.802073e+20
```

Comment: Thank you @Quinten, but I need Pooled estimate of variation. The formula as mentioned in the picture.

Comment: Hi @KABILAN, I added some code at the end of my answer where you can calculate the Pooled estimate of variance for A and B as an example.

Comment: The final code block assumes no missing data.  That may be correct here, but is not robust in general.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you tidy your data, so that each observation has its own row and each column represents a variable.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- pivot_longer(df, 1:6)

df <- mutate(df, 
       group = substr(name,start = 1, stop = 1),
       experiment = substr(df$name,start = 2, stop = 2),
       .keep = "unused",
       .before = 1)
```

```
> df
# A tibble: 36 × 3
   group experiment        value
   <chr> <chr>             <dbl>
 1 A     1          12305960197.
 2 A     2          11629654800 
 3 A     3          12503938418.
 4 B     1          14380818076.
 5 B     2          21440113143.
 6 B     3          20385779423.
 7 A     1          24169710612.
 8 A     2          25162283400 
 9 A     3          25733015601.
10 B     1          79582218995.
# … with 26 more rows
```

After this, you can use `group_by` and `summarise` to achieve the result.
I recommend reading R for data science chapters [tidy data](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html) and [data transformation](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html) to understand.

```
stat <- df %>%
  group_by(group)%>%
  summarise(n=length(value),
            var = var(value))
```

```
> stat
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  group     n     var
  <chr> <int>   <dbl>
1 A        18 8.81e20
2 B        18 1.02e21
```

```
pooled <- sum(stat$var*(stat$n-1)) / (sum(stat$n-1))
```

When group sizes are equal, you can also simplify the formula to (var1 + var2) / 2.

```
pooled_equal_n <- mean(stat$var)
```

```
> pooled
[1] 9.517714e+20
> pooled_equal_n
[1] 9.517714e+20
```

Note that the difference between this and the other answer stems from the fact that n = 6 for the other answer, for me it was n = 18. This is due to `sample.decomp` not working properly with the untidy data.